# Why is the first step for an attacker to get Reverse Shell after getting RCE?

Tags: penetration-test, reverse-shell, remote-code-execution

If someone is having a Remote Code Execution, that means, one can run the commands on the server, then why does he need to get the Reverse Shell?

Even though I can run system commands, then why do I go for Reverse Shell?

I am finding the primary reason behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remote code execution means you have successfully executed some specific code on the server. It does not mean you can execute anything *else* on the server, yet. The solution is to have the executed code make a connection back to you and allow you to send more commands for it to run. That's what a reverse shell is for. Without a reverse shell, you'd potentially have to re-exploit the server with a new payload over and over for each additional command you want executed. That would be a royal pain.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @forest's answer, the initial remote code execution method is often blind, with no access to command output.  Bootstrapping up into a remote shell means gaining access to command outputs, which are necessary for further exploration of the target.